# All material items are combined to a single material sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table as follows:

Header Number, Operation_Seq_Number, Material_Seq_Number, Material_item_id

I need to implement the following functionality.

Within the same Operation Sequence, the Item is used multiple times with different material sequences. I need to convert this so that all material items are combined to a single material sequence within the Operation Sequence.

So the need is to add the quantities of material sequence 114, 115, 116, 117 together and use for 114. The rows for 115 and 116, 117 should not exist.

I have tried to implement SQL for this, but I have failed thus far and I am looking for help to do this.

```
SELECT
    HEADER_NUMBER,
    WO_OPERATION_SEQ_NUMBER,
    MATERIAL_SEQ_NUMBER,
    MATERIAL_ITEM_NUMBER,
    MATERIAL_QUANTITYs
FROM xx
GROUP BY MATERIAL_ITEM_NUMBER
ORDER BY MATERIAL_SEQ_NUMBER ASC
```

This is far from what I need.  Looking for help please.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Please include your *desired results*.

Comment: Note, you appear to have an additional comma after your last column.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question, no images.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on it. The code is commented so you see what I'm trying to do.

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  HEADER_NUMBER nvarchar(50)
  , WO_OPERATION_SEQ_NUMBER int
  , MATERIAL_SEQ_NUMBER int
  , MATERIAL_ITEM_NUMBER nvarchar(50)
  , MATERIAL_QUANTITY int
);

INSERT INTO test (HEADER_NUMBER, WO_OPERATION_SEQ_NUMBER, MATERIAL_SEQ_NUMBER, MATERIAL_ITEM_NUMBER, MATERIAL_QUANTITY)
VALUES
  ('W001446666',10,114,'236328-01-1',100)
  , ('W001446666',10,115,'236328-01-3',1000)
  , ('W001446666',10,116,'236328-01-2',200)
  , ('W001446666',10,117,'98751-04',2410)
;

--The CTE prepares the data by selecting only the distinct columns
--so that our main SELECT will start out with a distinct row for each HEADER/WO_OPs...SEQ_NUM
WITH tMod as (
  SELECT 
    t.HEADER_NUMBER
    , t.WO_OPERATION_SEQ_NUMBER
    , MIN(t.MATERIAL_SEQ_NUMBER) as MATERIAL_SEQ_NUMBER_MIN

    --Remove if not needed. Here we show all the MATERIAL ITEM NUMBERS 
    --in a single column if you need them.
    , STUFF((
        SELECT ',' + t2.MATERIAL_ITEM_NUMBER
        FROM test as t2
        ORDER BY t2.MATERIAL_SEQ_NUMBER
        FOR XML PATH('')
      ),1,1,'') as MATERIAL_ITEM_NUMBERS
  FROM test as t
  GROUP BY 
    t.HEADER_NUMBER
    , t.WO_OPERATION_SEQ_NUMBER
) 
SELECT 
  tm.*
  , qtys.MATERIAL_QUANTITY

--First get the distinct rows from the tMod CTE
FROM tMod as tm

  --Now join to a derived table where are only calculating the SUM
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT
      t.HEADER_NUMBER
      , t.WO_OPERATION_SEQ_NUMBER
      , SUM(t.MATERIAL_QUANTITY) as MATERIAL_QUANTITY
    FROM test as t
    GROUP BY t.HEADER_NUMBER, t.WO_OPERATION_SEQ_NUMBER
  ) as qtys
    ON qtys.HEADER_NUMBER = tm.HEADER_NUMBER
    AND qtys.WO_OPERATION_SEQ_NUMBER = tm.WO_OPERATION_SEQ_NUMBER
;
```

| HEADER_NUMBER | WO_OPERATION_SEQ_NUMBER | MATERIAL_SEQ_NUMBER_MIN | MATERIAL_ITEM_NUMBERS | MATERIAL_QUANTITY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| W001446666 | 10 | 114 | 236328-01-1,236328-01-3,236328-01-2,98751-04 | 3710 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/mrV98JCQ)

Comment: That helps tons.  The only thing now is to get rid of the records that are > than the lowest  material_seq_number i.e the ones that have been summed up.

Comment: @JeremyReynolds What are you asking? To delete the other records from the table? I thought this was for a view or other non-destructive query because you only had a `SELECT` in your script, not a `DELETE` or `UPDATE`.